# Delete image with full url from cloudinary not working - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, cloudinary

I am trying to delete image from cloudinary via my express app, it is working only when i shorten the url to match the cloudinary folder that i created

```
pictures : "Images/zebre_s2gtto"
```

the full url of my image is

```
https://res.cloudinary.com/beloved/image/upload/v1589562378/Images/zebre_s2gtto.jpg
```

the main problem is that the image url is stored in the database and contains the full image url.

when i want to delete the image from cloudinary and from my database, if i mention the full url, the image is deleted from my database but not in cloudinary and if i mention the short url from cloudinary, image is deleted from cloudinary but the url is not deleted from my database because mongo is waiting for the full url of the image and cloudinary requires the shortened url.

my mongoose schema

```
{
  pictures : Array
}
```

what i am trying to do

```
deletePictures = async (req, res) => {
  const img = req.body.pictures
  try {
    await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(
      img, { invalidate: true, resource_type: "image" }, async (error, result)=> {
      if (error){
        return res.status(400).json(error)
      }
       await  Property.updateOne({$pull : { pictures: img }});
      res.json(result)
      })
  }
  catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json('Something went wrong')
  }
};
```

the postman test with PUT method

```
{
    "pictures" : "https://res.cloudinary.com/beloved/image/upload/v1589562378/Images/zebre_s2gtto.jpg"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to delete resources from Cloudinary via the URL and you need to use the [public_id](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#public_id) (i.e. the 'short URL' you refer to). The most common workflow is to store the `public_id` in your database as that is used for all API operations (delete, update etc). For URL generation, you can use the `public_id` and pass that into the Cloudinary SDK helper methods which construct the URLs locally and output the URL to the asset. These methods can be given any set of transformations options too. Please see the following section for examples for each SDK - https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#embedding_images_in_web_pages

I would recommend you migrate away from storing URLs and update your database to reference and keep the `public_id`. You can run a one-off script to extract the `public_id` from your existing URLs and then update the schema accordingly for your current records. For new uploads, you can grab the `public_id` parameter from the API response directly.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But why would you recommend storing public IDs instead of URLs. Im not sure why cloudinary wants to make their APIs difficult.  With imagekit all you have to do is use their "listFiles" function search your folder using a URL. Then you can extract the 'assetID' and use that to run their deleteFile function.  With cloudinary you need the publicID just to run a search for the asset.  Everything function requires a public ID with no way to get the ID without storing it when you upload an asset. Dumb.

Comment: It looks like here:                                                                             https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010819679-How-can-i-find-public-id-to-update-the-new-image-and-delete-the-old-one that the ID is easy to find on none transformed assets. Which would work in my case.  I am using cloudinary along with imagekit. Because I dont want to set up imagekits upload widget for the front end. I like cloudinarys better. So I will just store the URl and public_id in my database since they make it so easy to upload an asset.

Comment: @WovasteenGova - If you decide on storing URLs then you can use the method `extractPublicId` from the package `cloudinary-build-url` (NPM) to extract the public_id. Source: https://cloudinary-build-url.netlify.app/usage/extractpublicid/

Answer (score 1):

Well, for me, i stored both the public_id and url in the database so i could be flexible with my queries and checks rather than just storing the public_id and then using the Cloudinary SDK helper methods each time i need the url.

Comment: The SDK is useful since you can pass a public_id and a hash of transformation options and the SDK will build the URL to that asset for you. It's not recommended to deliver the original images/videos you upload to Cloudinary without any transformations. Originals are often large and thus unoptimized for web delivery so you're essentially making your users download more data than they need and in return, your bandwidth consumption on Cloudinary will be higher. You can read more about image optimizations via Cloudinary: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_optimization

Answer (score 0):

You can store only the url but specify `use_filename` as true and disable `unique_filename`.
By doing that, the filename (last potion of the stored url) will be the public id and you can use it to delete the resources.

It looks as below in C# but you can transfer to any language
[image]